# Regular Expression for ")" matching parentheses

Tags: java, regex

Every smiling face must have a smiling mouth that should be marked with either `)` or `D`.

I tried to do this using the following code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class SmileFaces {

  public static int countSmileys(List<String> arr) {
  String regx = "/^((:|;)(-|~)?|D|//))$/";
  int count=0;
  ListIterator<String> itr=arr.listIterator();

  while(itr.hasNext()){
    if(Pattern.matches(regx,itr.next())){
          count++;
        }
  }
      return count;
  }
}
```

I have tried this regex for smiling checking: `/^((:|;)(-|~)?|D|//))$/`

Comment: you need `\\)` instead of `//)`

Comment: When I tried this in test case it fails
' @Test
    public void test1() {
        List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
        a.add(":)"); a.add(":D"); a.add(":-}"); a.add(":-()");
        assertEquals(2, SmileFaces.countSmileys(a));
    }'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* just patch your current regex by correctly escaping `\\)` with two backslashes, but I think character classes are easier to read here:

```
String regx = "^[;:][~-]?[D)]$";
```

Note that Java regex patterns do *not* take delimiters as they would in another language such as PHP or Python, so I removed them from your pattern.  Also, if you wanted to use the above pattern with certain methods, such as `String#matches`, you could remove the `^` and `$` anchors.